# How can you get the value of a specific 'object' in realtime firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to know how to get this specific object name/value because I want to retrieve it for conditions in my android studio project.

[image]

I can get the instance of the 'table' Users but it is all my users that are retrieved. I would like to get one specific one so that i can target the childs of it.
`DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");`

Comment: `DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("a");`?

Comment: I don't want specifically the child "a", I want it in general so that for example if i go in the child 's' I can retrieve a specific child

Comment: Sorry @SoufianeB, but I'm not sure what you mean by that. If you want to get just the username of user `s`, that'd be `DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child("s/username");`. If that still isn't what you're looking for, can you edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show a bit more of the code you have, what output it generates, and what you want to output instead?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.